# getting HTTP Status 404 - /AdminLoginAction in struts1.2

Tags: struts

i given my sample code to get the HTTP Status 404 - /AdminLoginAction error

adminLogin.jsp

```
<form action="/AdminLoginAction">
```

struts-config.xml

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="AdminLoginAction" type="edu.form.AdminLogin" />
  </form-beans>
  <
  <action-mappings> 
    <action name="AdminLoginAction" path="/AdminLoginAction" type="edu.actions.AdminLoginAction" scope="request">
  <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp"></forward>
  </action>
  </action-mappings>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that this is a problem from web.xml. In there you have to have declared the Struts ActionServlet:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now that your servlet container knows about the ActionServlet, all there is to do is add a `<servlet-mapping>` element for it:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>...</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

First thing, check your `<url-pattern>`.

Secondly, just as a quick test, add an extension to your action (`<form action="/AdminLoginAction.do"`>) and a pattern `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>` and see if it works.

Also, not sure how your app is set up, but are you sure about that leading slash (/) in you action? Maybe its `<form action="/yourAppContext/AdminLoginAction">`?